# Jooq batch update with records in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, java-8, batch-processing, jooq

What is the proper way to do batch updates with JOOQ?

I have the following:

```
public void updateScores(Map<String, Integer> teamScores) {
    writeContext().transaction(config -> {
        DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(config);
        dslContext.batchUpdate(Maps.transformEntries(teamScores, (id, score) -> {
            TeamScoresRecord record = new TeamScoresRecord();
            record.setTeamId(id);
            record.setScore(score);
            return record;
        }).values()).execute();
    });
}
```

OR

```
public void updateScores(Map<String, Integer> teamScores) {
    writeContext().transaction(config -> {
        DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(config);
        dslContext.batchUpdate(
                dslContext.selectFrom(TEAM_SCORES)
                          .where(TEAM_SCORES.TEAM_ID.in(teamScores.keySet()))
                          .forUpdate()
                          .fetch()
                          .stream()
                          .peek(record -> record.setScore(teamScores.get(record.getTeamId())))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ).execute();
    });
}
```

Which of these is the recommended way to do batch updates?

Comment: Current;y I'm finding that the first one works and the second doesn't. I mean that the first one actually updates the rows, but the second does not because doing a select after that, produces the same rows as was in there before the update

Comment: Curious: Why do you use `peek()`, not `map()` in the second example? Also, how big are your maps?

Comment: @LukasEder `TableRecord::set` methods return void, and modify the record in place, so using map would have been an error because of the void, but using peek works because the item is modified in place. The maps are usually around 10k-15k elements

Comment: OK, I see. There's also `Record::with`, just in case, or you can generate fluent setters in the code generator. I'll look into the issue later

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the second approach, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is obviously very subjective and not easy to answer. Here are a few observations:

- Even with using the batch API in jOOQ, you're running a lot of individual queries, which incurs quite a bit of client/server overhead. This might be fine in your particular case, but it's usually not a bad idea to consider moving the entire logic into the database, e.g. by inserting your map in a temporary table and then merging the two data sets using a bulk `UPDATE` statement
- Both of your batches may cause deadlocks in the database, if two conflicting batches update the same records in a different order. I'm not sure if this is an issue in your code, but you may want to make sure this can never happen.
- The first approach will run one less query (the `SELECT` query, which might be quite expensive, depending on the size of the in-list). Without the `FOR UPDATE` clause, however, the first approach might have a higher deadlocking risk.
- The first approach will potentially run more update statements than necessary, e.g. for `ID` values that have been deleted in the meantime. The second approach prevents that from happening

Now, I don't know MySQL well enough to know if a bulk update statement might be better here, i.e. a statement of the kind:

```sql
UPDATE team_scores
SET score = CASE id
  WHEN :id1 THEN :score1
  WHEN :id2 THEN :score2
  WHEN :id3 THEN :score3
  ...
END
WHERE id IN (:id1, :id2, :id3, ...)
```

Perhaps you could benchmark this approach and compare it to batching (or combine it with batching, e.g. bulk update 10 rows and batch all these bulk updates)

Comment: I was testing this with H2 database because that's what we use for testing, so I'm not sure if it also works with mysql. Do you know a way to test jooq on arbitrary db's?

Comment: The database uses the InnoDB engine which implements row-level locking, so the second one should not cause the entire table to become locked. I tried the second version again and it works. I may have been using the wrong tables before. Anyways, from what you said, I will revert back to the old one because it seems to have the least potential of a belly up

Comment: @smac89: Please ask a new question about testing databases.